# Remove duplication in new fangled case with patterns

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

This works but is ugly. But I can't find how to make optional keys in a pattern. I am probably missing somehting obvious:

```
post '/api/users' do
  args = JSON.parse(request.body.read, {symbolize_names: true})
  case args
  in {name: name, email: email, bio: bio, password: password}
    User.create(args)
    200
  in {email: email, bio: bio, password: password}
    User.create(args)
    200
  in {email: email, password: password}
    User.create(args)
    200
  else
    400
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean `**` can be used for match any other keys but it is not needed as pattern matching a Hash is already partial unless you add `**nil`.

Comment: Should the `in {email: email, password: password}` pattern be enough? The first two hash variants would match that one too.

Comment: @spickermann : Why `in`? Shouldn't it be `when` inside a case statement? Or is the `in` a new addition in recent Ruby versions? I found only `case ... when ... when ... else ... end`.

Comment: @user1934428 See [Pattern matching](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/doc/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html) in Ruby. It has a similar syntax as case statements but works a bit differently.

Comment: @spickermann : Thanks a lot. I have the impression, that this was something added in Ruby 3.0. At least I can't find it documented in i.e. Ruby 2.6

Comment: That’s true. I think it was first introduced to 2.7-dev but then postponed and finally released with Ruby 3.0.